# Find patterns of a file in another file and print out a corresponding field of the latter maintaining the order

Tags: bash, awk, grep, pattern-matching

I've been trying for a while to solve this problem and I checked many posts (for example here [Print lines in one file matching patterns in another file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21388825/grep-awk-or-sed-print-lines-in-one-file-matching-patterns-in-another-file) or here [awk search for a field in another file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958083/awk-search-for-a-field-in-another-file)) without really finding what I am looking for. I need the solution with bash tools like sed, grep, awk (no python, R,...)

I have two files (much bigger than those):

file1:

```
   2   891299  0.50923964E-02     1248   4.713       1349.08
   3   245857  0.57915542E-02     1335   4.671       1369.65
```

file2:

```
   278    2645  2334659  0.75142      0.53123
   279    2643   245857  0.80439      0.56868
   500    1341   830677  0.74922      0.52958
   501    1339   882791  0.87685      0.61980
   502    1337   891299  0.63224      0.44680
```

In this example I want to find the pattern in column 2 of file1 in column 3 of file2 and print column 1 of the latter, for all the lines of file1 and maintaining the order given by file1.

A possible solution (I am aware is not bug free) is the following unacceptably slow bash loop:

```
for i in `awk '{print $2}' file1` ; do grep " $i " file2 | awk '{print $1}' ; done
```

which prints to screen:

```
502

279
```

Please note that a 'simple' solution like:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{pats[$2]; next} $3 in pats' file1 file2
```

is not appropriate as the order of the printing is given by file2 and not by file1 (i.e. it prints to screen first 279 and then 502).

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reverse files to be processed in awk and get the right output:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{pats[$3]=$1; next} $2 in pats{print pats[$2]}' file2 file1
502
279
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I should have mentioned that the ordering can be any (random) and cannot be adjusted by simple reverse of file1 like in this simple example, where it would work. 

File1 is usually composed of thousands of lines, as well as file2. Of course this does not mean that one can not use sort in the matching process in some clever way which I did not find.
Thanks again.

Comment: There is no reason to do any sorting. Your slow BASH script is also maintaining the column order as per their appearance in `file1` and this `awk` is also doing same. Just try it out on larger files and see.

Comment: Yes, you are right, thanks a lot, that solved my problem!